# Generate random number from two List<>

Tags: c#, linq

i want to generate random number from two list. i want to create a function where i pass how much random number from two list.

```
List<int> integers = new List<int>() { 54, 23, 76, 123, 93, 7, 3489 };
List<int> value2 = new List<int>() { 1, 3, 4, 6, 8, 17, 40 };
```

i want my result = `List<int> result = {54,40,123,17,3,1,3489,76...etc}`
When i run again the set of result  will be change.
Presently i am using this function that return List

```
public static List<int> GenerateRandom(int count)
        {
            // generate count random values.
            HashSet<int> candidates = new HashSet<int>();
            while (candidates.Count < count)
            {
                // May strike a duplicate.
                candidates.Add(random.Next(1,30));
            }

            // load them in to a list.
            List<int> result = new List<int>();
            result.AddRange(candidates);

            // shuffle the results:
            int i = result.Count;
            while (i > 1)
            {
                i--;
                int k = random.Next(i + 1);
                int value = result[k];
                result[k] = result[i];
                result[i] = value;
            }
            return result;
        }
```

i am calling the function

```
 List<int> vals = GenerateRandom(20);
```

But i want that the random number from two List<>  `List<int> integers` and `List<int> value2` . so how can i do this .

Comment: Do you mean that you want two lists as your return?

Comment: are you asking how to get `count` number of values from each list into one?  very unclear

Comment: Can you provide a sample input and one possible output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var result = 
    integers.Concat(value2)
    .OrderBy(x => random.Next())
    .Take(count)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: i have add result that i want as a output

Comment: Do you want all the items in the two lists to be included or do you want to take just some of the numbers based on `count`?

Comment: all the items in the two lists to be included i want this

Comment: So the size of the result would be = size of list1 + size of list2?

Comment: i want `List<int> result = {54,40,123,17,3,1,3489,76...etc}` means integers and  value2 suffle and make a new number

Comment: I am not sure I understand. My current solution considers all numbers on the two lists. It shuffles them all (**but not in place, it creates a new list**), but after shuffling them all, it takes only some of them based on `count`. If you want to take them all after shuffling, remove `.Take(count)` from my solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a general-purpose function to give you a random ordering of any number of sequences, like so:

```
public static IReadOnlyCollection<T> InRandomOrder<T>(Random rng, params IEnumerable<T>[] lists)
{
    return lists
        .SelectMany(x => x)
        .OrderBy(y => rng.Next())
        .ToList();
}
```

You can then pass as many lists as you like and get the contents back in a fully randomised order:

```
var list1 = new[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
var list2 = new[] {6, 7, 8};
var list3 = new[] {9, 0};

Random rng = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    var randomisedFirst5 = InRandomOrder(rng, list1, list2, list3).Take(5);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", randomisedFirst5));
}
```

There's a less efficient approach you can use that avoids the need for an instance of `Random`, but you should only use this for short lists or where you really don't care about performance. It uses `Guid.NewGuid()` to generate random numbers:

```
    public static IReadOnlyCollection<T> InRandomOrder<T>(params IEnumerable<T>[] lists)
    {
        return lists
            .SelectMany(x => x)
            .OrderBy(y => Guid.NewGuid())
            .ToList();
    }
```

Even the more efficient approach isn't the fastest. A faster way would be to use reservoir sampling to take the first N items that you want, and put them into an array which you shuffle using Knuth. That would make it a lot faster, at the expense of more complicated code - meaning you should only do it the fast way if it's really needed.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to select a number that exists either in list A or B, randomly, you can do:

```
    List<int> integers = new List<int>() { 54, 23, 76, 123, 93, 7, 3489 };
    List<int> value2 = new List<int>() { 1, 3, 4, 6, 8, 17, 40 };

    List<int> allInOne = new List<int>(integers.Concat(value2));
    Random r = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);


    /********************************
        For demonstration purposes
    ********************************/
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        var randomListIndex = r.Next(0, allInOne.Count - 1);
        Console.WriteLine(allInOne[randomListIndex]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use KeyValuePair

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> results = GenerateRandom(100);
        }
        static List<int> integers = new List<int>() { 54, 23, 76, 123, 93, 7, 3489 };
        static List<int> value2 = new List<int>() { 1, 3, 4, 6, 8, 17, 40 };
        static Random random = new Random();
        public static List<KeyValuePair<int,int>> GenerateRandom(int count)
        {
            List<KeyValuePair<int,int>> result = new List<KeyValuePair<int,int>>();

            for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                int firstValue = integers[random.Next(0, integers.Count - 1)];
                int seconValue = value2[random.Next(0, value2.Count - 1)];
                result.Add(new KeyValuePair<int,int>(firstValue,seconValue));
            }

            return result;
        }​
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually made a library a while back that handles some of this stuff : [Underscore.cs](http://github.com/konkked/Underscore.cs)

It's a nuget package so easy to install, the code to shuffle or take a sample randomly of two lists is :

```
        var ls1 = GenerateRandom(10);
        var ls2 = GenerateRandom(20);

        var mixer = ls1.Concat(ls2).ToList();

        //if you want all of the items shuffled use shuffle
        var result = _.List.Shuffle(mixer);

        //or if you want a subset randomly sorted use sample
        result = _.List.Sample(mixer);
```